# Vue3 Vuetify v-form restarts when form submit

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I try to use v-form, but I realised it restarts my web-app when the form was submitted.
It is very annoying because I lose the state if the app restarts.

This is my vue file:

```
<template>
  <v-form ref="form">
    <v-text-field v-model="title" label="Name" required></v-text-field>

    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <v-btn @click="asdf" type="submit" color="success" block class="mt-2">Save</v-btn>
    </div>
  </v-form>
</template>


<script setup>
function asdf() {
  console.log('please stay with me')
}
</script>
```

Comment: Refreshing the page is standard behavior of forms when submitting.  Prevent the native submit event with `<v-form ref="form" @submit.prevent>`

Comment: Yeah, really :) - it solved the issue. Thanks for the quick answer!